# Representation in $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$

Tags: representation-theory

By $A$ we denote the algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, generated by $y_1,y_2,s$ such that $y_1y_2-y_2y_1=0, s^2-1=0$ and $sy_1-y_2s-1=0$. Could you help me to build a homomorphism $A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[S_3]$, where $S_3$ is the permutation group on $\{1,2,3\}$, and $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$ is the corresponding group algebra. 
More generally, is there a way to build a homomorphism of an arbitrary $\mathbb{C}$-algebra onto $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$?
I will be grateful for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

By the given presentation of $A$, defining any homomorphism $A\to B$ yields  giving the images of the three generators $y_1,y_2,s$ in $B$, so that they satisfy the given rules.

So, we need to represent the elements $y_1,y_2,s$ actually *in* $\Bbb C[S_3]$ with the prescribed properties, i.e. $y_1y_2=y_2y_1$, $\,s^2=1$, $\, sy_1=y_2s+1$.

The condition $s^2=1$ seems restrictive enough.
In particular, it implies $\exists s^{-1}=s$ so that $y_1=sy_2s+s$. Writing this into the first condition,
we need $sy_2sy_2+sy_2=y_2sy_2s+y_2s\,.\ \ $ [ii]

If we just want to construct an arbitrary nontrivial homomorphism $f:A\to\Bbb C[S_3]$, then we are free to take $f(s)$ to be a transposition, say $f(s):=\,(12)\in S_3$. Then, if we choose $y_2$ so that it commutes with $s$, e.g. $f(y_2):=i\cdot (12)\in\Bbb C[S_3]$, then it also satisfies [ii], so we are left with
$f(y_1)= f(sy_2s+s)=(1+i)\cdot(12)$ in this example.